# VS Code import resolution error with Pylance (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

Having an import resolution error with pylance not recognizing packages. (Windows 10)

- Venv activated on the local directory
- Confirmed pip -list that the package is correctly installed
- Ran VS code as administrator
- Checked the package is installed in the /Lib/site-packages folder for my python installation

Receiving the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc123'
```

Inside the file, hovering over the broken import says

> "packageFoo" is not accessible

> Import "packageFoo" could not be resolved Pylance

Comment: Please check which python interpreter you are using from the executed command in the terminal. It looks like just an environment problem.

Answer (score 10):

I found many similar questions, but not this specific answer.

In vscode, locate the file dropdown on the top toolbar.

Select preferences > Settings (Ctrl +)

In the search bar, search for *pylance*

Scroll down to Python > Analysis: Extra Paths

[image: vscode pylance settings]

Click 'add item' button

Next step you need to identify the installation path for python in windows. In that path there is a 'Lib' folder. Under lib folder there is a 'site-packages' folder. This is the folder for all your pip installed packages.

For me it looked like this:

```
C:\Users\user_name_here\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
```

Copy this path and add it as the item in the pylance vscode settings.

Additionally: You can open the 'Python > Analysis: Indexing' settings below to edit a JSON file. Here you copy and paste the same path, with extra '' - backspace escape characters. Noting there is a comma after the first entry, if it exists.

Comment: The path can be relative too, like `./venv/Lib/site-packages`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have correctly installed **`Pylance`** when you open a `.py` file, this extension would be activate. Now check `settings.json` file and add the following sentence:
`"python.languageServer": "Default" or "Pylance"`.

It is probably that your problem is caused because **`Pylance`** is not *pointed* to the path where is your *library* installed or another package and the error is originated (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'abc123'`), then you may need to verify in your `settings.json` this configuration:

`python.analysis.autoSearchPaths` : `true`

`python.analysis.stubPath`:`./typings`

`python.analysis.extraPaths`:`["./folder"]` (if your project use a *specific* `folder`)

`python.analysis.autoImportCompletions`:`true`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there is a .py extension on the module.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Preferences > Settings > Search `pylance`
2. Find `Python> Analysis: Diagnostic Severity Overrides`
3. Click `Edit in settings.json`
4. Add following in `"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": { }`'s curly brackets `{ }`

```
        "reportGeneralTypeIssues": "none",
        "reportOptionalMemberAccess": "none",
        "reportOptionalSubscript": "none",
```

This should solve some un-intended underlines. There are other options to consider:

- `"reportMissingImports"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics related to import resolution.
- `"reportMissingModuleSource"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics for missing source files of imported modules.
- `"reportOptionalCall"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when calling something that might be `None`.
- `"reportOptionalIterable"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when iterating on something that might be `None`.
- `"reportOptionalContextManager"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when using something that might be `None` as a context manager.
- `"reportOptionalOperand"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when operating on something that might be `None`.
- `"reportUntypedBaseClass"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when a base class is untyped.
- `"reportUntypedNamedTuple"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when a named tuple does not have types.
- `"reportPrivateUsage"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when accessing a private member (i.e., begins with an underscore).
- `"reportConstantRedefinition"`: Controls the severity of diagnostics when a constant is redefined in a local scope.

Each of these options can be set to `"error"`, `"warning"`, `"information"`, or `"none"` depending on your preference.